# Making InputScope Property Work for Windows IoT Core

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, iot, windows-10-iot-core

What is needed in order to make the InputScope effective for Windows IoT Core development in order to limit the On-Screen Keyboard layout? I know from the [following article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280229.aspx) that:

> "This info applies only to the SIP. It does not apply to hardware
>   keyboards or the On-Screen Keyboard available in the Windows Ease of
>   Access options."

This question is more of a ***thought process*** one than asking for a code sample. What does a developer need in order to make such a major change in case it does not already exist?

Comment: You can check ["touch (or software keyboard)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/keyboard-interactions#touch-keyboard) .